# Optimizing while cycle with numba for error tolerance

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numba

I have a doubt when using numba for optimization. I am coding a fixed point iteration to calculate the value of a certain array,  named gamma, which satisfies the equation f(gamma)=gamma. I am trying to optimize this function with python package Numba. It seems as follows.

```
@jit
def fixed_point(gamma_guess):
    for i in range(17):
        gamma_guess=f(gamma_guess)
    return gamma_guess
```

Numba is capable of optimizing well this function, because it knows how many times it will perform the opertation, 17 times,and it works fast. But I need to control the tolerance of error of my desired gamma, I mean , the difference of a gamma and the next one obtained by the fixed point iteration should be less than some number epsilon=0.01, then I tried

```
@jit
def fixed_point(gamma_guess):
    err=1000
    gamma_old=gamma_guess.copy()
    while(error>0.01):
        gamma_guess=f(gamma_guess)
        err=np.max(abs(gamma_guess-gamma_old))
        gamma_old=gamma_guess.copy()
    return gamma_guess
```

It also works and calculate the desired result, but not as fast as last implementation, it is much slower. I think it is because Numba cannot optimize well the while cycle since we do not know when will it stop. Is there a way I can optimizate this and run as fast as last implementation?

Edit:

Here is the f that I'm using

```
from scipy import fftpack as sp
S=0.01
Amu=0.7
@jit 
def f(gammaa,z,zal,kappa):
    ka=sp.diff(kappa)
    gamma0=gammaa
    for i in range(N):
        suma=0
        for j in range(N):
            if (abs(j-i))%2 ==1:
                if((z[i]-z[j])==0):
                    suma+=(gamma0[j]/(z[i]-z[j]))   
        gamma0[i]=2.0*Amu*np.real(-(zal[i]/z[i])+zal[i]*(1.0/(2*np.pi*1j))*suma*2*h)+S*ka[i]
    return  gamma0
```

I always use `np.ones(2048)*0.5` as initial guess and the other parameters that I pass to my function are `z=np.cos(alphas)+1j*(np.sin(alphas)+0.1)` , `zal=-np.sin(alphas)+1j*np.cos(alphas)` , `kappa=np.ones(2048)` and `alphas=np.arange(0,2*np.pi,2*np.pi/2048)`

Comment: [This](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3031) suggests, that float comparisons are way slower in `numba`, so maybe you have to translate your float comparison to an integer one

Comment: I tried modifying my function to only do integer comparisions, but it does not seems to help

Comment: What happens if you do `gamma_old=gamma_guess` instead of `gamma_old=gamma_guess.copy()`? I don't see a reason for copying. Later this evening I might have time, to try some solutions myself

Comment: Yeah sorry, an habit I acquired because sometimes things didn't work and it solved some problems , but nothing seems to change when removing it this time. Many thanks for trying by yourself later.

Comment: Now, that I posted my answer; why were you using `np.max`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a small test script, to see if I could reproduce your error:

```
import numba as nb

from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def f(x):
    return (x+1)/x


def fixed_point_for(x):
    for _ in range(17):
        x = f(x)
    return x

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def fixed_point_for_nb(x):
    for _ in range(17):
        x = f(x)
    return x

def fixed_point_while(x):
    error=1
    x_old = x
    while error>0.01:
        x = f(x)
        error = abs(x_old-x)
        x_old = x
    return x

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def fixed_point_while_nb(x):
    error=1
    x_old = x
    while error>0.01:
        x = f(x)
        error = abs(x_old-x)
        x_old = x
    return x

print("for loop without numba:")
ipython.magic("%timeit fixed_point_for(10)")

print("for loop with numba:")
ipython.magic("%timeit fixed_point_for_nb(10)")

print("while loop without numba:")
ipython.magic("%timeit fixed_point_while(10)")

print("for loop with numba:")
ipython.magic("%timeit fixed_point_while_nb(10)")
```

As I don't know about your `f` I just used the most simple stabilizing function, that I could think of. I then ran tests with and without `numba`, both times with `for` and `while` loops. The results on my machine are:

```
for loop without numba:
3.35 µs ± 8.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
for loop with numba:
282 ns ± 1.07 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
while loop without numba:
1.86 µs ± 7.09 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
for loop with numba:
214 ns ± 1.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The following thoughts arise:

- It can't be, that your function is not optimizable, since your `for` loop is fast (at least you said so; have you tested without `numba`?).
- It could be, that your function takes way more loops to converge as you might think
- We are using different software versions. My versions are:

  - `numba  0.49.0`
  - `numpy  1.18.3`
  - `python 3.8.2`

Comment: I forgot to mention that the input of my function is a numpy array, my f outputs an array that constains my fixed point.

Comment: No, it took far less than the 17 that I put there, I am sure that it converges because I have tested it and it gives the same result as the while version,  but much faster.

Comment: Then I would say, it would be best, if you edit your question and give an example of such an `f` and corresponding `gamma` guesses

Comment: I have to say, that I'm by no means an expert at this, just trying to help and understand the problem. Did you try `nopython=True` and got an error btw?

Comment: I'm working with numpy 1.16.3, numba 0.45.1 and python 3.6.9

Comment: I also forget to mention that it does not work with '(nopython=True)', I think because I am using a scipy function inside f

Comment: I'll edit my question with the function f that i'm using, thanks for the help